# indexing quantity list element in python

Tags: python

I have a text file where I have this information:

BRIEF DESCRIPTION A herbaceous, upright, often much branched, slightly woody plant, up to 2-4 m in height, with spiny pubescence, large yellow flowers, and fruits which at maturity dry to a longitudinally dehiscent capsule, 25 cm long or more. USES The young immature fruits are eaten fresh, cooked or fried as vegetables and the can be frozen, canned or dried. Fruits have medicinal properties. Ripe seeds contain 20% edible oil and they can be used as a substitute for coffee. In India, mucilage from the roots and stems has industrial value for clarifying sugarcane juice in gur manufacture. Dried okra powder is used in salad dressings, ice creams, cheese spreads, and confectionery. The stems provide a fiber of inferior quality. GROWING PERIOD Annual. May require 50-90 days to first harvest and the harvest period may continue up to 180 days. COMMON NAMES Okra, Ochro, Lady's Finger, Gumbo, Gombo, Cantarela, Quingombo, Rosenapfel, Bindi, Bhindee, Bhindi, Mesta, Vendakai, Kachang bendi, Kachang lender, Sayur bendi, Kachieb, Grajee-ap morn, You-padi, Ch'aan K'e, Tsau Kw'ai, Ila, Ilasha, Ilashodo, Quimbambo, Kopi arab, Khua ngwang, Krachiap mon, Dau bap. FURTHER INF Scientific synonym: Hibiscus esculentus. Okra originated in South-East Asia. Most varieties grow well in the lowland humid tropics up to elevations of 1000 m. Adapted to moderate to high humidity. Okra is a short-day plant, but it has a wide geographic distribution, up to latitudes 35-40°S and N. Yields of green pods are often low, about 2-4 t/ha owing to extreme growing conditiuons, but up to 10-40 t/ha may be produced.

I am using the library quantulum which extracts all the measurement automatically.


BriefDescription is a variable that contains text 
The QuantDescription stores all the quantity from the BriefDescription 
I need to get the values that are "metre" string in the second parameter of the quantity tuple 
I need to figure out how to get the index of the tuples

```
    quantsDescription = parser.parse(BriefDescription)
    quantsUses = parser.parse(Uses)
    quantsPeriod = parser.parse(GrowingPeriod)
    print 'BriefDescription Quant:'
    print quantsDescription
    print 'Uses Quant:' 
    print quantsUses
    print 'GrowingPeriod Quant:'
    print quantsPeriod
    for i in quantsDescription:
        print type(i[1])  # indexing the second element of the tuple?
```

This the output list for quantsDescription:
[Quantity(2, "metre"), Quantity(4, "metre"), Quantity(25, "centimetre")]

Comment: What do you mean by "stores all the quantity from the BriefDescription"? And why do you think you have tuples? What is a `Quantity`?

Comment: I have edited my question. I am extracting the measurements from the text (stored in BriefDescription variable) using the "quantulum" library. it gives me all the quantities in a list format that i thought were tuples.  I am very new to python so I might get some words wrong. sorry

Comment: Thanks, I found my answer! I just was having problem with the documentation for quantities. It did not seem to have a very good API reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
print quantsDescription[0].unit.name # to get the unit's quantity
print quantsDescription[0].value # to get the amount of the quantity
```